# React Native true is a reserved word

Tags: react-native

I'm a real beginner in React Native, trying to prevent a double tap.

```
      <LoginButton ref={btn => { this.btn = btn; }}  onPress={this.disableButton} text='test' dis={false}>
```

and the button

```
  disableButton = () => {
        var touchable = this._touchable;
        touchable.disabled={true};
    }
```

Gives me an error that true is a reserved word.

Well, I'm stuck at that point.

My version is 0.50.4

Comment: You should disable the button by adding the props `disabled` to the component instead. ex: `<TouchableOpacity disabled={true}>`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try deleting the curly braces like

```
 disableButton = () => {
    var touchable = this._touchable;
    touchable.disabled=true;
}
```